# How to prevent ember.js change the structure of the template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using ember.js 0.9.2 (but this issue also occurs in HEAD revision) and it is changing my template's markup structure. I have a template like this:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="appointment-cell">
            <td colspan="1">
                <span class="reserved">
                    {{text}} 
                </span>
            </td>
    </script>
```

And my JS code like this:

```
        var AppointmentCellView = Ember.View.extend({
            templateName: 'appointment-cell',
            text: 'Some name',
        });
        window.App = Ember.Application.create({
            init: function(){
                this._super();
                AppointmentCellView.create().appendTo("#the_tr");
            }
        });
```

But the view is rendered like this:

```
<div id="ember142" class="ember-view">
    <span class="reserved">
        Some name 
    </span>
 </div>
```

Don't know, but it seems that ember.js is removing my td element. This is the output when I use `tagName: 'td'` in the view class:

```
 <td id="ember142" class="ember-view"></td>
```

It doesn't even render the content! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It took me awhile to figure this one out...

Your problem is that you do not have properly formatted HTML here so the browser is disregarding the incorrectly formatted markup. Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/Gb64t/) and look at the [results](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ud3323/Gb64t/show/) in your inspector.

If you need any other help please don't hesitate to ask!

P.S. Please use jsFiddle to show your errors. It helps us out :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't see any malformed HTML in mine or your example. The only thing that have changed between appointment-cell-fixed and appointment-cell-broken is the fact that you're using an entire <table> strutcture. When I do `AppointmentCellView.create().appendTo("#the_tr");` I'm appending to an existing <table>, with an existing <tr>, like this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/f9eWr/3/. In your example, you try to append the td outside of a table.

Comment: [This would be](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/Z2M4V/) the more correct way to do what you are trying to do. But the way you did it should still technically work... you might want to file an issue on github.

Comment: Oh wow! This solves the issue then! I'll post the issue on github ASAP! Thanks again!

Comment: You know what... yes there is malformed HTML in your example. Let me explain:

When you append an Ember view object to the DOM that object must be wrapped in some tag. Since you did not specify one it wrapped everything in a <div> so your HTML looked like this: `<table><tbody><tr id="the_tr"><td>Some data</td><div class="ember-view"><td><span class="reserved">The text</span></td></div></tr></tbody></table>`

which is malformed. I [updated the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/Z2M4V/) to show what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

To explicitly sum up the lesson I think is being implicitly provided here by the far wiser and more experienced folks: if you're using inline templates, make sure the markup/elements inside of your Ember/handlebars template can be parsed on a standalone basis, and won't be blown-up by the insertion of the Ember `<div>`. Don't put `<table>` outside of your template, and your `<tr>`'s and `<td>`'s inside. Make sure the whole table is inside, so it can be parsed as a unified whole.

However, if you're using non-inline templates, like so:

```
var AppointmentCellView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'appointment-cell',
    text: 'The Text',
    tagName: 'td',
    attributeBindings: ['colspan'],
    colspan: 1
});
```

then you have the option of defining the type of element that Ember will wrap around your template content. In this case above, Ember's winged steed for delivering your template content will be a `<td>` rather than a `<div>`, which will parse perfectly nicely inside of your table.